# what are the differences between "python setup.py test" vs "pytest {package}"?

Tags: python, pytest, setuptools, github-actions

I am building a continuous integration workflow using GitHub actions. This workflow will be used to run unit tests and test build status. The workflow will be used by a number of different people who have developed python package so I am trying to make it as general and modular as possible. My goal is to seperate the tasks of running unit tests and testing the build status of these packages, which leads me to my question, what are the differences between the commands `python setup.py test` and `pytest {package}`?

Specifically,

1. Does running unit tests with the command `pytest {package}` automatically build your package or is it not possible to run unit tests without building your package?
2. I know that setup.py is the build script for setuptools and I have read what the command `python setup.py test` does and it says it will: run unit tests after in-place build. So does this command use pytest by default then?

I also saw in the setuptools docs the build command, so to take a stab at answering my own questions, I would do `pytest {package}` for running unit tests only and `python setup.py build` to test the build status of the package.

Is that correct?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does running unit tests with the command pytest {package}
>   automatically build your package?

No, it doesn't, and you don't need it to - you don't need the package to run your tests.

> Is it not possible to run unit tests without building your package?

It is possible.

> I know that setup.py is the build script for setuptools and I have
>   read what the command `python setup.py test` does and it says it will:
>   run unit tests after in-place build. So does this command use pytest
>   by default then?

It does run the configured tests, so this depends on your setup. Running `python setup.py test` is deprecated as already mentioned, so you usually don't have to worry about this - use `pytest` directly in your CI environment. Note though that some Linux distros still do run this by default on deployment, so if you want to distribute your package you may still have to test that.

To run `pytest` via `setup` you probably need something like this in your `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    packages=find_packages(),
    tests_require=['pytest'],
)
```

Comment: a note, `python setup.py test` is deprecated as is `pytest-runner`

Comment: Thanks, removed `pytest-runner`. Deprecation of `python setup.py test` was already mentioned.

Comment: ah ok I assumed since `tests_require` is only used by `setup.py test` -- didn't read the rest, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't answer about the differences, but...

> **Warning:** `test` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Users looking for a generic test entry point independent of test runner are encouraged to use [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/).

-- [*setuptools* documentation on the command "`test` - Build package and run a unittest suite"](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/commands.html#test-build-package-and-run-a-unittest-suite)